# Cannot drop table in pandas to_sql using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to drop an existing table, do a query and then recreate the table using the pandas to_sql function. This query works in pgadmin, but not here. Any ideas of if this is a pandas bug or if my code is wrong?

Specific error is `ValueError: Table 'a' already exists.`

```
import pandas.io.sql as psql
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine(r'postgresql://user@localhost:port/dbname')

c = engine.connect()
conn = c.connection

sql = """
drop table a;
select * from some_table limit 1;
"""
df = psql.read_sql(sql, con=conn)
print df.head()
df.to_sql('a', engine)

conn.close()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why are you doing this like that? There is a shorter way: the `if_exists` kwag in `to_sql`. Try this:

```
import pandas.io.sql as psql
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine(r'postgresql://user@localhost:port/dbname')

c = engine.connect()
conn = c.connection

sql = """
select * from some_table limit 1;
"""
df = psql.read_sql(sql, con=conn)
print df.head()
# Notice how below line is different. You forgot the schema argument
df.to_sql('a', con=conn, schema=schema_name, if_exists='replace')

conn.close()
```

According to [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html):

> replace: If table exists, drop it, recreate it, and insert data.

---

Ps. Additional tip:

This is better way to handle the connection:

```
with engine.connect() as conn, conn.begin():
    sql = """select * from some_table limit 1"""
    df = psql.read_sql(sql, con=conn)
    print df.head()
    df.to_sql('a', con=conn, schema=schema_name, if_exists='replace')
```

Because it ensures that your connection is always closed, even if your program exits with an error. This is important to prevent data corruption. Further, I would just use this:

```
import pandas as pd
...
pd.read_sql(sql, conn)
```

instead of the way you are doing it.

So, if I was in your place writing that code, it would look like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine(r'postgresql://user@localhost:port/dbname')

with engine.connect() as conn, conn.begin():
    df = pd.read_sql('select * from some_table limit 1', con=conn)
    print df.head()
    df.to_sql('a', con=conn, schema=schema_name, if_exists='replace')
```

Comment: I don't know if this is a new thing, but apparently pandas can (now) also use the engine directly. E.g. `df.to_sql('a', con=engine, schema=schema_name, if_exists='replace')`