# Remove pandas dataframe from sql_alchemy database

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

I'm pretty new to databases.
How can we remove a pandas dataframe from a sqlite database using `flask_sqlalchmey`?

I added a dataframe to the database using `df.to_sql`. But how would I remove it?

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import pandas as pd

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///site.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]})
df.to_sql(name='my_table', con=db.engine)
```

The only thing I found was this question: [Cannot drop table in pandas to_sql using SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38840208/cannot-drop-table-in-pandas-to-sql-using-sqlalchemy) But it does not help me or I don't understand it.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to drop `my_table` table, you can use

```
db.engine.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;')
```

Comment: It works, many thanks! So in the end this had nothing to do with pandas, right? Just removing any table from the database.